# Why do I receive an error when installing config package?

Tags: npm, config

I'm new to nodeJS & mongodb and I'm following an online course that told me to install the config package. So I typed `npm i config` in my terminal but I'm getting EDTIMEDOUT error when trying to install. I've already tried multiple times and my internet connection should be stable. I've never encountered this issue before when installing a package, does anyone know how to solve this?

**My log:**
[image]

Comment: request is taking loner time to connect, I believe it has to do with ipv6 address are not resolving properly. Try disabling ipv6 on your system.

Comment: I found similar bug on [github](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/4163)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @bogdanoff said, disabling my ipv6 solved the issue and the package is now downloaded!